# Flexbox layout with multiple rows having 3 items in each

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have the 3 unordered list items take up the whole block spaced out evenly, with the 1st one at the start the 2nd one in the middle and the last one touching the end of the block.

I am trying to do it with flex box but currently I am having difficulty, I figured justify-content: would work for this task, but its not doing anything.

Here is the end result I am trying to achieve:

[image: final]

[link to codepen](http://codepen.io/staycreativedesign-1472670666/pen/jBRmyd)

**Example:**

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.area--third-amenities--list {
  width: 375px;
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul li {}
```

```html
<div class="area--third-amenities--list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `flex-basis:33.33%` on the `li`s so they stay 3 on one line and `text-align:center`

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.area--third-amenities--list {
  width: 375px;
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align:center;
}

ul li {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="area--third-amenities--list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PwKgUnO.png" />
      <p>
        50px
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center` on the `li`..

```
li
   flex: 1 1 100px
   text-align: center
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqJKwK